# Is it possible to access the console if you have already redirected standard out?

Tags: java, redirect, console, redirectstandardoutput

### Context:

- I have a simple program with a bunch of `System.out.println()` calls
- depending on command line arguments I either send standard out to
  console or to file
- I also have a very basic `Debug` class with a `Debug.print()` call I use to print debug info to console when my program has problems

### Problem:

I never want the `Debug.print()` call to be sent to a file, it's just temporary info for me. Of course when I redirect standard out to file, Debug info is sent there as well

### Attempted Solutions:

1. I tried to use java.io.Console with `System.console().writer().println()` but it returns a `NullPointerException` when standard out is redirected as specified in the javadocs.
2. The other way I tried was to 'save' the console in a variable before redirecting standard out. This works fine if I do it in the class that does the redirecting, but in the `Debug` class, I can't be sure that someone hasn't already redirected standard out by the time I set my console variable...

### Question:

Is there any simple way of writing to the java console no matter what standard out is doing?

Comment: Save the original reference of `System.out`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yup, that's #2 in my attempted solutions list. I just can't be 100% sure that the reference will be saved before it is changed.

Comment: Why not? Save it at your program's entry point.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah it works ok and it's what I'm doing now, I have it saved in a static initialisation clause in my Debug class, I just would rather not have to remember to reference the Debug class before changing standard out. I guess the direct answer to my question is no.

Comment: It would be possible but would need some dirty hacky reflection. You don't want to do that here. Saving the reference is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write to the JVM process’ stdout handle by creating a new `FileOutputStream` referring to the `out` handle. If you want to have the same features as `System.out`, just wrap it into a `PrintWriter`:

```
PrintStream oldOut=new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out));
oldOut.println("I ignore whether System.out has been redirected");
```

This only bypasses what has been set within the JVM using `System.setOut(…);`. If the stdout of the process itself has been redirected, e.g. using `>` on the command line, this won’t help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.err`, which writes to "standard error" instead of "standard output".  That's the normal way on Unix-like OS's and on Windows for tools to display informative or error messages to the user, when the tools' standard output is likely to be redirected.  Note that on both Unix and Windows, the user can include a redirection option to redirect standard error to a file (which may or may not be the same as standard output).  This is better than trying to write directly to the console, which would not allow the user that choice.

Comment: This makes sense with the setup that I have, but I guess all my Debug info will now be highlighted in scary red! From the responses so far, I'm guessing the straight answer to my question is no?

Comment: @mallardz Highlighted in red--why?  Is this an IDE that's catching the error output?  It might be necessary to specify what environment you're using to run the program; solutions that access the console directly may not work right in all environments.

Comment: Sorry yes I'm using eclipse. Tbh I just thought there must be a simple call to get hold of a console and that I'd missed it in the docs.

Comment: @mallardz Maybe there is.  I've never tried doing this.  Of course, you could also see if there's a way to configure Eclipse to change its display from "scary red" to "calming green" or "electric puce" or "burnt umber" or ... sorry, can't fit the names of all 64 Crayolas in this comment.

Comment: I think I'll go for 'calming green'. I have a very jumpy disposition.

Answer (score 0):

Before you change `System.out` to something different, save a reference to it named for example `stdout` and whenever you want to write to the console you use `stdout`.

Comment: That's #2 in my attempted solutions list. I just can't be 100% sure that the reference will be saved before it is changed.

Comment: Sounds like you deal with threads or you have something running parallel. Considered using synchronized block?

Comment: Well I'd like it to be thread safe if possible, but really I just thought there might be a simple call to print to a console and I wouldn't have to remember that I had to reference my Debug class first and only then redirect output etc.